# Is it possible to access the $routeParams object in the $routeProvider declaration?

Tags: angularjs

In the following code:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Is it possible to somehow acces the 'phoneId' value in the templateURL, for example something like this (I know it doesn't work but it's to explain what I'm asking):

```
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/' + $routeParams.phoneId + '.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
```

The aim being to load an HTML file named with the phoneId.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.when('/phones/:phoneId', {
    controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
    templateUrl: function (params) {
        return 'partials/' + params.phoneId + '.html';
    }
})
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks ever so much.